# Is it possible to override/Update Prototype version 1.4 to version 1.7 on another site via javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, conflict, jquery

(I'm not quite sure how to title this question, feel free to edit).

I'm embedding a JS widget on another website that uses Prototype.js Version 1.4.  I'm using jQuery in my widget, so it's running in no-conflict mode already.  (I read somewhere that version 1.4 of prototype "just doesn't play well" with jQuery, even in no-conflict mode.  I can elaborate, but that is probably a different question.)

I can't change which version of Prototype the client website included, but if I could "unload and reload" prototype with the latest version 1.7 that would fix my conflict woes.

Any ideas if this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not likely.

You could change the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag that includes Prototype 1.4. This could be done in a `$(document).ready();`

However, the challenge would be doing so (pulling in Prototype 1.7) before the rest code/events on the page ran/fired. With both jQuery and Prototype events competing, it's not trivial to know what has fired and what has not. Much less *reloading* code.

I'm sure it's possible with some kind of blocking call. Maybe someone will post one. But then you have to deal with some kind of synchronous call, what if the resource is unavailable, etc.

I think you'd have a easier time figuring out how to change the source. That's the right thing to do long term anyway.